# Why are STDistance results so small?

Tags: sql-server

Im trying to get familiar with spatial data using sql server 2008.

I use book: http://www.beginningspatial.com/

and there is sample data: http://www.census.gov/geo/cob/bdy/zt/z500shp/zt06_d00_shp.zip

I uploaded it to my sql server database and Spatial results are presented well. Everything seems to be ok but when I tried to calculate distance between 2 geometries result is really small.

For example 0.27

The same is if I try to calculate STLength of given region. Result also is very small like 0.19 for example.

I wonder why the results are so small. I used SRID 4269 importing data.

Does anyone have any idea why is it like that ? I think that the result whould be in meters.

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 8):

The units of the project 4269 are decimal degrees, so probably your answer reflects that bias, if you are using the 'Geometry' type. If you want more useful units, try loading your spatial data using the 'Geography' type, or re-project it to a local planar projection in order to use the 'Geometry' type.